# Apache POI : Excel Sheet Column size grow automatically as per max data in cell

Tags: apache-poi

I am using Apache POI for Generating report but it not resize column . as per maximum content of cell in each column how i can get it

I tried with following statement but doesn't work for me !

```
  sol1:tried-----     DataSheet.AutoSizeColumn(index);
  sol2:tried-----   DataSheet.setColumnWidth(index,size);
```

I don't want to set size manually it will considered Automatically as per cell content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow the sample at http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Autofit

Make sure to call the auto-size methods only once **after** adding all the content as it is not a persistet setting, but rather done right at the time when it is called.

Also look at the note about formulas, it might be necessary to ensure they are calculated before autosizing.